# how to call a htmlhelper from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

is it possible to call a htmlhelper from javascript ?

I have tried to include it in my javascript variable but the razor view just renders the actual text rather than the dropbox.

```
   var statusSelector = ['<label for="selectList">Status</label>',
                        '<input id="selectstatusList" name="selectList" type="hidden">',
                        '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp',
                         '@Html.StatusDropDownListFor(model => model.Reportstatus)',
                        '<div class="clear"></div>'].join('\n');
```

This is all that gets rendered....

```
   @Html.StatusDropDownListFor(model => model.Reportstatus)
```

To put it into context, I only want this dropdown to appear based on the users selection in another dropdown (which would be the previous step in the workflow before this StatusDropdown) 
Please note this is an mvc 3 application using razor views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not.  When you call `return View();` in your action method, the view engine parses the view and generates the html. When it encounters a `@Html.Helper` method, that method generate specific html (e.g. input, select etc.). It can not recognise a string within a script tag as being a `@Html.Helper` (and if it did, to would render it at the time).

Javascript has no concept of what a HtmlHelper is. HtmlHelpers generate html on the server side and Javascript runs on the client.

I suggest you create the dropdown inside a hidden element and use javascript to show it based on the selection in the other dropdown. Alternatively you could use AJAX to return the html for the dropdown.

Comment: Ya I had a bad feeling that was gonna be the only solution ! cheers